# Multiple variables in a single axis in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have job on jenkins, to which I pass config as a variable on the axis.
I'd like to add a second variable to the same job.
So now I have:

Campaign1: A

Campaign2: B

etc.
I'd like to introduce a second variable so I'll have

Campaign1: A Alpha

Campaign2: B Beta

If I introduce a second axis - I'll get a matrix build, and I don't want that.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as it turned out the easiest way to do it is to make the job parametrized. Or write a bunch of exceptions if that's your cup of tea and you have time for that.

Update: In the end I just put a delimiter between 2 variables and passed them as one and then I cutted them in a script.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 this is still not possible and `exclude{}` seems to be the best option to archive that. I was able to figure out, that you can at least define multiple values for `axis{}` in `exclude{}`, that should save some writing ([undocumented](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix)).

Example:

```
matrix {
    axes {
        axis {
            name 'PHP_VERSION'
            values '7.4', '8.0', '8.1', '8.2', '8.3'
        }
        axis {
            name 'PHPUNIT_CONFIG'
            values 'phpunit.xml.dist', 'phpunit9.xml.dist'
        }
    }

    excludes {
        exclude {
            axis {
                name 'PHP_VERSION'
                values '7.4', '8.0'
            }
            axis {
                name 'PHPUNIT_CONFIG'
                values 'phpunit.xml.dist'
            }
        }
        exclude {
            axis {
                name 'PHP_VERSION'
                values '8.1', '8.2', '8.3'
            }
            axis {
                name 'PHPUNIT_CONFIG'
                values 'phpunit9.xml.dist'
            }
        }
    }
}
```